# Access fields of Firestore document and print output in different labels Swift4

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to learn Swift and am making okay progress with Firestore but I'm struggling to understand the fetch/get methods in a way that allows me to manipulate the data I get back from a document.

Specifically, I've made a fairly simple CRUD app that adds a 'workout' to Firestore and then has buttons to update/delete the entry.

What I want to do now is :

Fetch the document and then print the fields in different labels.  I think this means I have to get the document into an array and then somehow select each "step" in the workout and change the label.text but I'm really stuck!

I've checked a lot of answers (like the one here for Android [how to search at firestore document's field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46876905/how-to-search-at-firestore-documents-field)) but I can't seem to find a **simple** explanation that helps me achieve what I'm trying (hopefully in a way that gives me an understanding of 'why' as much as 'how' so I hopefully won't have to ask these basic questions in future so much!

Here's my code :

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseFirestore

class WorkoutBuilderController: UIViewController {

    //create a label to print one of the steps - I'd need 2 more of these to print step2 and step3

    @IBOutlet weak var workoutLabel: UILabel!
    let db = Firestore.firestore()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    //function to add the workout document

    @IBAction func generateButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

        db.collection("Workout").document("Arnolds Bananas").setData([
            "Step1": "Push Up",
            "Step2": "Viking Press",
            "Step3": "Sit Up"
        ]) { err in
            if let err = err {
                print("Error writing document: \(err)")
            } else {
                print("Document successfully written!")
            }
        }


    }

    //function to delete the document/workout

    @IBAction func deleteButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

        db.collection("Workout").document("Arnolds Bananas").delete() { err in
            if let err = err {
                print("Error removing document: \(err)")
            } else {
                print("Document successfully removed!")
            }
        }

    }

    //function to update step 1 from 'push ups' to 'jumping jacks'

    @IBAction func updateButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

        db.collection("Workout").document("Arnolds Bananas").updateData([
            "Step1": "Jumping Jacks"])
        { err in
                if let err = err {
                    print("Error updating document: \(err)")
                } else {
                    print("Document successfully updated")
                }
        }

    }

    //try to make a function that gets the document and prints step1, step2 and step3 in different labels

    @IBAction func readButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

        let documentreference = db.collection("Workout").document("Arnolds Bananas")

        documentreference.getDocument { (document, error) in
            if let document = document, document.exists {
                let workoutReturned = document.data().map(String.init(describing:)) ?? "nil"
                print("Document data: \(workoutReturned)")
            } else {
                print("Document does not exist")
            }
        }

    }

}
```